# VS 2015 RC Build Error NotifyPropertyWeaver: Unhandled exception occurred Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbDebugException: Unknown custom metadata item kind: 6

Tags: visual-studio-2015

So trying to build my first real project in VS 2015 RC I get the error:

```
NotifyPropertyWeaver: Unhandled exception occurred Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbDebugException: Unknown custom metadata item kind: 6
```

After trying various things, including Cleaning the Solution, clearing the Read-Only from the solution folder, taking ownership of the folder, I'm still unable to build the solution.

This seems to be a related bug, but it looks like it was resolved back in 2014:
https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/issues/186 I'd assume this would already be in the RC version.

**Update:** Just installed VS 2015 Enterprise, and I'm having the same problem there as well!

Answer (score 1):

Seems everybody is having the same issue. Until the official fix arrives, you can try [this](http://dissipatedheat.com/2014/10/28/curious-case-of-code-contracts-and-roslyn/) workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Ours ended up being a deprecated dll, `notifypropertyweaver` updating to the new `Fody.PropertyChanged` library fixed the problem.